# Divide height in 3 with LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I want to place 3 separate `LinearLayout` controls inside a `RelativeLayout`, and divide the available height between the 3 `LinearLayout` controls, so that they all have an even height.

I have tried, `weightSum`, as well as `gravity`, but none of these work as I wrongly assumed it would. I have read about `layout_weight`, but this is not available in `LinearLayout`.

I can give each of them a static height, but how would I know the available space for each and every device the app may run on?

Here is my current code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_image">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:weightSum="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:weightSum="1"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am still learning Android development, so any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I use "layout_weight" in most cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following layout will have 3 `LinearLayout`s  evenly divided vertically

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_image">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am accepting this solution, as I originally wanted to use LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read about `layout_weight`, but this is not available in `LinearLayout`

No you are wrong `LinearLayout` supports assigning a weight to individual children with the `android:layout_weight` attribute.

> I want to place 3 separate `LinearLayout` controls inside a `RelativeLayout`, and divide the available height between the 3 LinearLayout controls, so that they all have an even height.

Better adding 3 separate `RelativeLayout` inside `LinearLayout` and then giving `android:weightSum="3"` to the parent `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to each child `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Why would you suggest I use Relative layouts instead?

Comment: You were asking for using relative layout so that i suggested to nest relative layout inside linear layout. Is this why you un-accepted the answer  ?

Comment: Yes. Although your soution solved my initial problem, I don't understand why I should rather place RelativeLayout within LinearLayout. I am certain that LinearLayout would be best suited for my needs, as I need to arrange some icons horizontally within them.

Comment: @android_noob Please accept the answer after being sure the answer is better one. Do not make such habit. You are even taking your "thank you" back with you. You clearly told above that *I want to place 3 separate LinearLayout controls inside a RelativeLayout* so that I gave you suggestion to reverse your logic instead. That is another way but I thought you want to use RelativeLayout as well inside. It's OK. Once you get sufficient reputation you can downvote either. I wont stop.

Comment: Why would I want to downvote your answer? Instead of being negative, try and understand, that still, you have failed to mentioned why I should change the design to use 3 RelativeLayouts instead of my original 3 LinearLayouts. I appreciate your effort in helping me, and if I had enough reputation, I would upvote, not downvote.

Comment: @android_noob No I am not negative it's ok. I read your description and answered descriptively and others saw your codes and shown their one. Your thank you was enough for me, But you deleted that as well so that I was upset. Not to be worried.

Comment: The only reason I deleted that comment, was because I mentioned in it, that this is what I wanted, but yes, I should have been a bit more patient, and given your answer more thought than just accepting.  Thanks for your efforts, really. I see I can now upvote, so +1 for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you are looking for

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @android_noob no worries :)